# Apache2 still shows default page after trying to configure it

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

Someone has set Apache2 (ubuntu 14.04) to load the default page at this address: `example.com:8822`. I checked `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and saw no reference to port 8822. So, I went on to to creating my website like this:

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin mail@myweb.net
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com
ProxyPass / http://example.com:8822/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8822/
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/chris/project/project/wsgi.py
Alias /static/ /home/chris/project/project/staticfiles/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_project.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_project.log combined
<Location "/static/">
Options -Indexes
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

and finally

`sudo a2ensite example.com.conf`

and

`sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`

and

`sudo service apache2 reload`

Now, in `sites-enabled` there is only one entry to example.com.

However, when loading example.com:8822 it shows the default apache2 web page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the result of `ls /etc/apache2/sites-available/`? Try creating a file called `/var/www/html/index.html` and see if that is the actual location of your default website. I would guess that you still have the default config file in place.

Comment: apart from example.com.conf `sites-available` includes `000-default.conf` and `default-ssl.conf` files. And this is the actual location of the default website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration file for Apache will provide a definition for your default website. It's files will be at `/var/www/html/`. If you don't want that site to show up then you need to remove its configuration file (`rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`).

One more thing that you'll want to do is fix your new file. I **strongly** suggest that you begin simple and work your way up. Try this one first:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /www/example1
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll notice that your configuration doesn't include a `DocumentRoot`. This directive is very important for each vhost.